# jQuery not working

Tags: 7, javascript

I have this code in page.tpl.php which is a link that toggles an option menu and makes the first link "I'm a link" become red:

```
<a href="www.google.com" class="select1">I'm a link</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="select_button1">Click me!</a>
<br/>
<select class="select2" size="5" style="display:none">        
    <option name="test" value="" class="first">Select</option>       
    <option name="test" value="" class="">Opt1</option>       
    <option name="test" value="" class="">Opt2</option> 
</select>
```

Then in template.php I have this code, which injects the script on every page:

```
function basic_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'basic') . '/js/script.js', array( 
    'scope' => 'footer', 
    'weight' => '15' 
  ));
}
```

Finally, in script.js I have this that I suspect being the culprit:

```
(function ($) {
$('.select_button1').click(function() {
    $('.select1').css('color', 'red');
    $('.select2').toggle();
});
}(jQuery));
```

What's the problem? The problem is that when I click on the "Click me!" link nothing happens..

In JsFiddle it works just fine http://jsfiddle.net/WYm4H/120/

Comment: @rooby I just added it by using drupal_add_js(). But it still shows up in Firebug..

Comment: Please read [Managing JavaScript in Drupal 7](https://drupal.org/node/756722), especially [Behaviors](https://drupal.org/node/756722#behaviors) part.

Comment: @Mołot Thank you, I read that up already ;) Added the "(function ($) { ... })(jQuery);" bit but it still won't work :/

Comment: Side note: if you want to add js on every page you can do so in the info file of your theme. See https://drupal.org/node/171205#scripts

Comment: @dotbitcode if you really read that, **why your code is not a behavior?** And if you willingly ignore Drupal practices, what do you expect from us?

Comment: @rooby Followed your advice and added it in the info file instead.

Comment: @Mołot yes sorry you're right..but don't understand how it has to be structured to work..Would this be good "(function ($) {
Drupal.behaviors.scriptModule = {
attach: function (context, settings) {
$('.select_button1').click(function() {
    $('.select1').css('color', 'red');
    $('.select2').toggle();
});
}
};
}(jQuery));" ?

Comment: @dotbitcode seems so. Easiest way to tell? Try ;) And post self-answer if it works.

Comment: @Mołot will try now.

Comment: Hello again. I removed an answer from the question. It's still in [revision history](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/posts/104502/revisions), of course. Please post it as an answer when it'll be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using Drupal.behaviors. Save the following code below into a JS file and add it to your THEMENAME.info file.

```
(function($){

/**
* Change color of link.
*/
Drupal.behaviors.themeChangeColors = {
  attach: function(context, settings) {
    $('.select_button1').click(function() {
      $('.select1').css('color', 'red');
      $('.select2').toggle();
    });
  }
};

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found what was wrong..Here is how I adapted the code to Drupal.

```
(function ($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.scriptjs =  {
    attach: function(context, settings) {

      $('.select_button1').click(function() {
    $('.select1').css('color', 'red');
    $('.select2').toggle();
});

    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Made a "boilerplate" for other people who struggle with this.

```
(function ($) { // <--------------------------- Add
  Drupal.behaviors./* Put the name of your script/module/whatever in place of this comment (if you have no idea the name of the script file should suffice) */ =  { // <---------- this
    attach: function(context, settings) { // <- first

       //Replace this with your jQuery code (leave the rest untouched until necessary!)//


    } // <---------- Add
  }; // <----------- this
})(jQuery); // <---- last
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `jQuery` instead `$`
For this case [jQuery :contains() Selector](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_sel_contains) need use 
not

```
drupal_add_js('
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("p:contains(is)").css("background-color", "yellow");
            });
        ', array('type' => 'inline', 'scope' => 'footer', 'defer' => TRUE));
```

but

```
drupal_add_js('
            jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                jQuery("p:contains(is)").css("background-color", "yellow");
            });
        ', array('type' => 'inline', 'scope' => 'footer', 'defer' => TRUE));
```

And not need

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com
```